# Typescript 'await' doesn't appear to wait?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Please forgive the noobie error, I am trying Ionic coming from a C# background so that might be part of the problem.
I am trying to get a stored token from Ionic storage but am struggling to get my head around promises and .then so decided to use 'await' since I am used to that in c#.

This is part of an Api Service I want to construct so need to get my http headers in order and so in the constructor I retrieve the token to add it in.
Here's a section of the Api service TS file:

```
      export class ApiService {

    ServerUrl = environment.url;
    BearerToken: string;
    GetUserDetailsEndPoint = 'api/Account/GetUserDetails';
    UpdateUserDetailEndPoint = 'api/Account/UpdateUserDetail';
    TokenEndPoint = 'Token';
    RegisterEndPoint = 'api/Account/Register';
    httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.BearerToken
      })
    };

      constructor( private http: HttpClient,
      private storage: Storage,
      private alertController: AlertController ) {

      this.getBearerToken();    // I put this in a function cos not sure how the async stuff plays out in a constructor
      console.log('Have awaited the token and its value is:' + this.BearerToken);
    }

    async getBearerToken()  {
      this.BearerToken = await this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY);
    }
```

So quite simply, the 'this.BearerToken' is undefined when sent to the console. (The value does exist in the store).
Its obviously some kind of asynch type of issue but I am struggling to understand why 'await' doesn't..?
I have read around quite a bit but most times folks are using the .then functionality with promises. What am I missing here?
Thanks

**EDIT**
Having taken the advice from Igor here, I move the initialization out of the UserService and into the ngOnInit of my menu page which is where I first need to use it. I am within the same realm of getting user info from local storage rather than the token, but it is the same issue.
So I guess I'm failing to understand something still... the function to get the stored user is this:

```
    async getUserStore() { // Populate the data object with the stored info
    this.data = await this.storage.get(USER_DATA);
    console.log('getUserStore: email = ' + this.data.Email);

    }
```

where this.data is a UserData object within the service class.
However, this function still returns a promise rather than awaiting before returning. Do I need to make it return something specific in order for the await to actually await? e.g.

```
        return await this.storage.get(USER_DATA);
```

or use the .then approach, and if so, what is the point of 'await' ing it at all?

My calling function looks like this: (to work as expected)

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.user.getUserStore().then(() => {
  console.log('ngOnInit - menu page, this.user email is: ' + this.user.data.Email);
  if (this.user.data && !this.user.data.DetailsComplete) {
    this.showAlert('Your Details are incomplete, please can you complete them?');
  }
  console.log('ngOnInit - menu page');
});
```

}

Whereas with the await in the async function I would expect it to look like this: (which doesn't work)

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.user.getUserStore();
console.log('ngOnInit - menu page, this.user email is: ' + this.user.data.Email);
if (this.user.data && !this.user.data.DetailsComplete) {
  this.showAlert('Your Details are incomplete, please can you complete them?');
}
console.log('ngOnInit - menu page');
```

}

So how (using await) would I make it actually wait in the called function? or can't I?
Cheers

Comment: You're not awating the call `this.getBearerToken();` in the constructor.  You shouldn't do async things in constructors for other reasons, but that's why it's not done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not make `async/await` calls in a `constructor` as constructors do not support `async/await` keywords. If you want to use `async/await` you should make sure that all `Promise`s are awaited or resolved using the methods like `then()` *and* if you do use `async/await` the method with the `await` call(s) has it's signature prefixed with `async`.

One of the the design flaws of putting "complex" logic in the constructor is that your type becomes difficult to unit test. The other, in this case, is that you can't use the keyword `await` because you can't mark a constructor as `async`.

#### Option 1 - provide a new method marked as async/await

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: Storage,
    private alertController: AlertController ) {}

async initialize() {    
    await this.getBearerToken();
    console.log('Have awaited the token and its value is:' + this.BearerToken);
}

async getBearerToken()  {
    this.BearerToken = await this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY);
}
```

#### Option 2 - use a standard promise method like then

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: Storage,
    private alertController: AlertController ) {}

initialize() {  
    this.getBearerToken().then(_ => console.log('Have awaited the token and its value is:' + this.BearerToken));
}

async getBearerToken()  {
    this.BearerToken = await this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY);
}
```

---

#### Edit

I am going to take a guess you want this for a component or directive. You only need to implement `OnInit` with method `ngOnInit` in your component or directive. That is where you should place code you want to run when your component is created.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  myBearerToken: any;
  constructor(private service: AuthService) { }
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.myBearerToken = await this.service.getBearerToken();
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can also make this same call using `then` even if what you are calling is using `async/await`.

---

#### Edit 2

In your last example of how you wish to change to to await you never use await or async. It should be:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  await this.user.getUserStore();
  // rest of code
```

Comment: Thank you Igor and JBC, OK, so don't call async functions in the constructor is what you are saying, but moving it out to another async function doesn't help if I need to get the storage token in the constructor. The storage function is an Ionic library which is async so I can't control that. So can I ask, what if anything I should do to call the initialize function from inside the constructor... or in reality, how do I get hold of the stored token. I mean, I guess I could have some sort of 'startup' service that makes the stored data available as globals or something? i.e. find another way :)

Comment: @BrettJB - See edit I added to the answer. If that is not what you are looking for you need to tell us how you want to get the information, what is the actual consumer because services do not live on their own.

Comment: Yes, that will work and I am going to mark as answer because you have been kind enough to help me. My mistake I guess is knowing what levels a component, service etc and where they all fit. Trouble with trying to learn too many things at once - Angular, Typscript, Ionic...  Thanks again, Brett

Comment: The typical pattern is either to retrieve the value elsewhere and pass it in to the constructor or to have an "initialization" method that's called asynchronously.  This goes hand in hand with displaying some kind of "in progress" indicator to the user, such as a loading spinner.

Comment: Hi again Igor, I have put an edit in my question that I think demonstrates my issue more precisely. I wonder if you could point me somewhere this is better explained? Thanks again...

Comment: ah... ok thanks... I wasnt sure about adding async to ngOnInit.. I'll give it a try.